# Multiple table JOIN throws 'Not unique table/alias' error

Tags: php, mysql

The following query throws an error:

```
SELECT * FROM proposal_data
  INNER JOIN proposal_data
      ON proposal_data_second.proposal_id = proposal_data.proposal_id

  INNER JOIN proposal_data_second   
      ON proposal_data_third.proposal_id =  proposal_data_second.proposal_id
  INNER JOIN proposal_data_third
      ON proposal_data_fourth.proposal_id = proposal_data_third.proposal_id
```

the error is:

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'proposal_data'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what exactly is the "problum" ?

Comment: Mysql gives following error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'proposal_data'

Comment: To begin with, read the error messages: `ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'proposal_data'`. You need to be using a table alias (e.g. see http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p8.php )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining tables wrongly.

In your current query you are joining tables before declaring it:

e.g. take first three lines

```
SELECT * FROM proposal_data
  INNER JOIN proposal_data
      ON proposal_data_second.proposal_id = proposal_data.proposal_id
```

here you are joining `proposal_data` with `proposal_data_second` before declaring `proposal_data_second` table.

Also you don't need to use table name `peoposal_data` twice:

```
SELECT * FROM proposal_data
  INNER JOIN proposal_data --This is invalid syntax
```

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM proposal_data
   INNER JOIN proposal_data_second
           ON proposal_data_second.proposal_id = proposal_data.proposal_id
   INNER JOIN proposal_data_third
           ON proposal_data_third.proposal_id = proposal_data_second.proposal_id
   INNER JOIN proposal_data_fourth
           ON proposal_data_fourth.proposal_id = proposal_data_third.proposal_id
```

For more see [MySQL: `JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: "Query is wrong" sounds vague, explain him or throw out that point where he was going wrong

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Yeh updated.

Comment: @hims056 mysql shows following error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'proposal_data'

Comment: @user2118352 - Did you try a correct query?

Comment: @hims056 Now it is showing #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'proposal_data_third'

Comment: @user2118352 - A little mistake. Now try the updated query